# How to handle async $http in for loop, js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a quite simple js routine:

```
$scope.tracks=[some_array]
new_tracks=[some_array]
for(var i = 0; i < new_tracks.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        temp_track = Object.keys(new_tracks[i])[0];
        info = new_tracks[i][temp_track];
                                    
        if($scope.tracks[temp_track] === undefined) {
            $http.get("http://ip/get_current_track/" + temp_track).then(function(data) {
                $scope.old_track = data.data;
                    if($scope.old_track !== undefined) {
                        /* some calc with $scope.tracks & info */
                    } else {
                        /* some calc with $scope.tracks & info */
                    } // else
            }); // http
        } else {
            /* some calc with $scope.tracks& info */
        }
    })(i);
}
```

I know, that here I should use closure, but also here we have async $http(I use angularjs).

After this loop $scope.tracks data is mixed up.. I dont know why, I think this is because async $http, am I right?

** UPD ** 2nd Question:  Why closure is not neede here? (when no function inside loop)

```
$scope.tracks=[some_array]
new_tracks=[some_array]
for(var i = 0; i < new_tracks.length; i++) {
        var temp_track = Object.keys(new_tracks[i])[0];
        var info = new_tracks[i][temp_track];

        if($scope.tracks[temp_track] === undefined) {
            if (info['ok]) {
                    if($scope.old_track !== undefined) {
                        /* some calc with $scope.tracks & info */
                    } else {
                        /* some calc with $scope.tracks & info */
                    } // else
            }); // http
        } else {
            /* some calc with $scope.tracks& info */
        }
}
```

Comment: `temp_track` and `info` are not scoped down to the function.  That's part of the whole reason to have the closure.  Put `var` or `const` on them.

Comment: Damn right! put the answer you want me accept!